# How to express an equally differentiate array

Tags: nouns, mathematics

This might involve some math knowledge.

I tried to express the name of such an array:

```
1, 3, 5, 7
```

which has this feature:

every two numbers close to each other have a difference of `2`, which is a constant.

We call it **Equal Difference Series**, but I can't find any information on Google. So this might be the wrong name.

Comment: @BlaiseZydeco, that's what I am looking for. thanks. could you please post your answer then I will be able to upvote you?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Mathematics.

Comment: Hi, @EdwinAshworth, I read the tag *mathematics* definition in this site: *This tag is for questions about the usage and meaning of mathematical terminology and the names for mathematical entities in English.*. So clearly, I was asking in the right place, ;)

Comment: On Mathematics SE, the tag 'terminology' is affixed to 4389
'Questions on the usage and meaning of words in mathematics, the names for mathematical entities, and other such questions'. On ELU, there are fewer than 300 questions carrying the tag 'mathematics'. You start the question 'This might involve some math knowledge.'  You set out an AP in the usual maths format. People who wish to enquire about a maths problem normally gravitate to Mathematics SE, so they're (far  –  look at the ratio 4400 : 300) less likely to look for an answer to 'What name is given to ...

Comment: a sequence such as 1, 3, 5, 7?' here on ELU than over on Maths SE. So clearly, there is a **better** place to ask.

Comment: You get cold and went to a hospital, the doctor said: Sorry, even if we are able and claimed to cure a cold, but there is a better place over there around the corner, they are more experienced and clearly cured many more patients, so go there!

Comment: You get a cold and go to a hospital. You rush to the pharmacy, where you know they have drugs that can help you. Hey, who cares that the hospital has its own protocols? It might take three minutes more to go through the proper channels.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I won't post any question like this here anymore, but not because you won the debate. But thank you for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper term for this is [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Answer (score 0):

how about "incremental progression" for a progressively increasing series?
since if you have something like this: 7, 5, 3, 1.
you then call it "decremental progression".
and again, "constant incremental/decremantal progression" for implying the  constant nature of the change.
there is also the term "**incremantal/decremangal array**", and again you could say "constant incremantal/decremantal array".
just something i remembered from the time spent doing some programming.

Comment: Hi, @Faradin, _arithmatic progression_ is the right term for me. thanks anyway.

Comment: yeah. just googled it and apparently AP is the better choice.